# How to use Apple Mail App instead of Gmail when mailing an event from Apple Calendar app

Tags: gmail, email, calendar, mac

I am using Apple Calendar App (with Google Calendar data). I am used to "mail event" to share them with someone (not to invite them, just to let them know of an event). When doing so, Calendar App used to launch Mail App with an email containing an .ICS file that the receiver of my mail could import in its own calendar.

This behaviour changed recently (last Mac OS update maybe...?). Now when I do "mail event", the calendar app opens "Google Calendar" in a browser window with a title/body about the event, but no ICS file. So the receiver has nothing to import to add the event to its calendar.

Does anyone knows how to change what app is launched when "mail event" is clicked? Or maybe someone found a workaround to this problem by using another mechanism to share .ICS file. (Note: it is not possible to do it from Google Calendar as far as I could tell...)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about using an installable app. Questions about Apple Mail App might be on topic in [apple.se] and/or [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail > Preferences > General > Default email reader: Mail.app

Comment: thanks! That was indeed simple :-) I don't know how this configuration was changed from "Mail.app" to "Chrome" at some point.... I guess Chrome asked me and I clicked without noticing.... but strange because I had the same problem on 2 different laptops. Anyway, thanks a lot Evan !